# diff on contents of a file

Tags: linux, bash-scripting, diff

i'm trying to do a diff on two files and compare the contents and if they are different send an email. Below is my script that I cannot get to work for some reason. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script alert.sh runs every hour in cron
# Created march 15, 2018 Author Dave Taylor

# Variables
frm="Datafile-Monitor@mycompany.com"

# For testing email and script
recipients="dave@mycompany.com"


# This is the Data file checked every Midnight for website results done by curdata.sh script. Results go to the curfile.fil
current=/scripts/results/curfile.fil

# This is the NEW data output file where website is checked every hour done by newdata.sh script. Results go to the datafile.fil
new=/scripts/results/datafile.fil

dpd=`cat /scripts/results/datafile.fil`
dte=`/bin/date`


# check if the contents of the file has changed since midnight.

    if diff $current $new &>/dev/null

        then

# Log it
    echo "$dte" >> /var/log/datapod
    echo "Data file is $dpd" >>  /var/log/datafile

    else
# Create the message

    echo "Current STL Datafile has changed TO:$dpd" > /scripts/results/mesg

# send the email
    mail -s "Alert Data File has changed" -r "$frm" $recipients < /scripts/results/mesg

sleep 3

#Now we update the current data file with the most up to date info.
cat /scripts/results/datafile.fil > /scripts/results/curfile.fil
fi
```

Comment: How is it failing? What have you done to debug it?

Comment: Use `set -x` to make `bash` print every command that follows. This way you'll know what gets executed (note: the command to get back to normal behavior is `set +x`, in case you ever need this).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
frm="Datafile-Monitor@mycompany.com"
recipients="dave@mycompany.com"
current=/scripts/results/curfile.fil
new=/scripts/results/datafile.fil
log=/var/log/datafile
msgfile=/scripts/results/mesg
dte=`/bin/date`
diff $current $new &>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ];  then
    echo "${dte}: Data file is: $new " >>  $log
else
    echo "Current STL Datafile has changed TO: " > $msgfile
    cat $new >> $msgfile
    mail -s "Alert! Data File has changed" -r "$frm" $recipients < $msgfile
    sleep 3
    cat $new > $current
    echo "${dte}: Data file has changed. Sent mail to $recipients" >>  $log
fi
```

Comment: The syntax `if diff $current $new` is vastly preferrable to `diff; if [ $? -eq 0 ]` so this is not really an improvement.  Generally speaking, the unquoted file names are rather unnerving, too.  See also http://shellcheck.net/ for syntax checks.

Comment: This seems to be a [Try this!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196188) answer. Explain why you want the asker to try that and what you changed.